# Liquibase update very slow when migrate from 3.5.5 to 3.6.0 or superior

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I m using liquibase in version 3.5.5 and my script ran fast, about 20 secondes to execute all of my script from scratch.

Recently i have update my version to 3.6.3 and now, global time of execution is pass to 20minutes!! I have change nothing in my scripts, if i came back to 3.5.5 it take 20 secondes. I have also test 3.8.0 (the last release at this day).

I have put log level to DEBUG and in 3.5.5 script is executed like this :

```
INFO 18/09/19 16:20: liquibase: changelog-master-postgresql: classpath:db/changelogs/db.changelog-2018-06-04 15-08-postgresql.xml::1528117671-3::test: Foreign key constraint added to area (default_calendar_id)
INFO 18/09/19 16:20: liquibase: changelog-master-postgresql: classpath:db/changelogs/db.changelog-2018-06-04 15-08-postgresql.xml::1528117671-3::test: ChangeSet classpath:db/changelogs/db.changelog-2018-06-04 15-08-postgresql.xml::1528117671-3::test ran successfully in 20ms
```

Same with 3.8.0:

```
14:57:53.849 [DEBUG] [main] liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot - Excluding seadog_pam_dev.production_item_input_aud.rev
14:57:53.862 [DEBUG] [main] liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot - Excluding seadog_pam_dev.seadog_revision.id
14:57:53.862 [DEBUG] [main] liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot - Excluding seadog_pam_dev.production_item_input_aud.revend
14:57:53.870 [DEBUG] [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - Reading ChangeSet: classpath:db/changelogs/db.changelog-2018-06-04 15-08-postgresql.xml::1528117671-3::test
14:57:53.870 [DEBUG] [main] l.database.core.PostgresDatabase - Executing Statement: liquibase.statement.core.AddForeignKeyConstraintStatement@437de8fb
14:57:53.870 [INFO ] [main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - ALTER TABLE area ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bqrilyrciwrbknvfcklavyvdt FOREIGN KEY (default_calendar_id) REFERENCES calendar (id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
14:57:53.871 [DEBUG] [main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - 0 row(s) affected
14:57:53.871 [INFO ] [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - Foreign key constraint added to area (default_calendar_id)
14:57:53.881 [INFO ] [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - ChangeSet classpath:db/changelogs/db.changelog-2018-06-04 15-08-postgresql.xml::1528117671-3::test ran successfully in 9274ms
```

as you can see just for this case ran successfully pass from 20ms to 9274ms!! if i add all other i pass to 20minutes.
In 3.8.0 i see many `liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot`...

I don't see anything in changelog that can explain this, does anybody have the same problem? can i deactivate something in this version?

thanks

Comment: You have an Liquibase problem, better to ask Liquibase support.

Comment: Is there any way that you can provide a sample project that shows the difference? The only other suggestion would be to get a trial version of YourKit java profiler and profile the execution of the operation with both versions to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: @SteveDonie no simple to have a sample project, for now we stay in 3.5.5 and when i got time, i will try to debug what happen and do a pull request if needed to liquibase project or correct/update my script.

Comment: OK. I will try to set something up and do performance profiling.

Comment: Please, do you have any news regarding this? I have the same problem: slow  migration process compared with older versions and also, some migrations problems related with csv loads.

I opened some jira tickets, but none have been reviewed...

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3455

Comment: @Bringer i have open issue diretly on github project but for now, not yet resolved...https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1171